# Calendar event not displaying?

Tags: android, calendar

I am using the below code to add an event in my

```
ContentResolver cr = getCurrentContext().getContentResolver();
                ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

                Calendar startDate = Calendar.getInstance();
                startDate.setTimeInMillis(1538677837930L);
                Calendar endDate = Calendar.getInstance();
                endDate.setTimeInMillis(1538674237930L);

                values.put(CalendarContract.Events.DTSTART, startDate.getTimeInMillis());
                values.put(CalendarContract.Events.DTEND, endDate.getTimeInMillis());
                values.put(CalendarContract.Events.TITLE, "event test");
                values.put(CalendarContract.Events.DESCRIPTION, "event desc");
                values.put(CalendarContract.Events.CALENDAR_ID, 3);
                values.put(CalendarContract.Events.EVENT_TIMEZONE, TimeZone.getDefault().getID());

                Uri uri = cr.insert(CalendarContract.Events.CONTENT_URI, values);
                long eventID = Long.parseLong(uri.getLastPathSegment());
                Log.e("event", "" + eventID);
                setCalendarEventId(eventID);
                Toast.makeText(getCurrentContext(), contentDatum.getGist().getTitle() + " added to your calendar.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

However I do receive the calendar event id. But the event is not shown in the calendar app.

I am running my code on Samsung device with OS 7. Any solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that the default calendar ID may differ from device to device.
Firstly had to get the calendar ID programmatically with the below code
private int getCalendarId() {

```
    Cursor cursor = null;
    ContentResolver contentResolver = getCurrentActiveContext().getContentResolver();
    Uri calendars = CalendarContract.Calendars.CONTENT_URI;

    String[] EVENT_PROJECTION = new String[]{
            CalendarContract.Calendars._ID,                           // 0
            CalendarContract.Calendars.ACCOUNT_NAME,                  // 1
            CalendarContract.Calendars.CALENDAR_DISPLAY_NAME,         // 2
            CalendarContract.Calendars.OWNER_ACCOUNT,                 // 3
            CalendarContract.Calendars.IS_PRIMARY                     // 4
    };

    int PROJECTION_ID_INDEX = 0;
    int PROJECTION_ACCOUNT_NAME_INDEX = 1;
    int PROJECTION_DISPLAY_NAME_INDEX = 2;
    int PROJECTION_OWNER_ACCOUNT_INDEX = 3;
    int PROJECTION_VISIBLE = 4;

    cursor = contentResolver.query(calendars, EVENT_PROJECTION, null, null, null);

    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        String calName;
        long calId = 0;
        String visible;
        do {
            calName = cursor.getString(PROJECTION_DISPLAY_NAME_INDEX);
            calId = cursor.getLong(PROJECTION_ID_INDEX);
            visible = cursor.getString(PROJECTION_VISIBLE);
            Log.e("Calendar Id : ", "" + calId + " : " + calName + " : " + visible);
            if (visible.equals("1")) {
                return (int) calId;
            }

        } while (cursor.moveToNext());

        return (int) calId;
    }
    return 1;


}
```

Below code is just for information purpose to know how many calendars are present and their id's

```
        String projection[] = {"_id", "calendar_displayName"};
    Uri calendars;
    calendars = Uri.parse("content://com.android.calendar/calendars");

    ContentResolver contentResolver = getCurrentContext().getContentResolver();
    Cursor managedCursor = contentResolver.query(calendars, projection, null, null, null);
    String calID="1";
    if (managedCursor.moveToFirst()){
        String calName;

        int cont= 0;
        int nameCol = managedCursor.getColumnIndex(projection[1]);
        int idCol = managedCursor.getColumnIndex(projection[0]);
        do {
            calName = managedCursor.getString(nameCol);
            calID = managedCursor.getString(idCol);
            Log.e("calName",""+calName);
            Log.e("calID",""+calID);
            cont++;
        } while(managedCursor.moveToNext());
        managedCursor.close();
    }
```